# Dynamic variable naming in Python

Tags: python-3.x, variables

So far I have seen that the majority of responses to this kind of question advice using a list.
All well and good in many circumstances, however not when needing to assign a specific variable name.
Please read and understand that I'm not asking the same question as has been before before downvoting this, if the answer is truly the same (use list/dict) please explain how this is implemented in my specific case,

In my situation I have a pyqt5 gui and I want to change the text of the labels in certain circumstances:

```
    for layer in layerlist:
        # reads all layers into a dictionary
        layers[layer] = gpd.read_file(gdb_path, driver="FileGDB", layer=layer)
        gdf = layers[layer]

        if gdf.empty: # loop to find empty datasets
            self.lab_1.setText("Empty dataset")
```

Obviously using `self.lab_1` as a static variable will be of little use.

More useful would be to have the label be the same as the layer name so it can address the cotrrect label in the gui.

```
        if gdf.empty:
            self. + layer + .setText("Empty dataset")
```

Using `+` works fine for adding variables to strings, but wont work in this case. I've done this before in things like php, is it possible in Python, if so how?

Comment: Can you tell me what type of variable lab_1 is exactly ?

Comment: lab_1 will just be the label in the gui `self.lab_1.setText("Empty dataset")`, `self.lab_2.setText("Empty dataset")` ... rather than an incremental INT it would be better if it was named as the layer in the dict STR. `self.his_cop_loe.setText("Empty dataset")`, `self.his_cop_topo.setText("Empty dataset")` In php if I remember you can use placeholders `{var_name}`.

Comment: `exec()` seems to be a way forward `mycode = 'self."layer".setText("empty")'`
                 `exec(mycode)`